# Find &lt; to < using jQuery

Tags: jquery, replace

I need to add image tags to WP eCommerce's Custom Meta fields but when I add it, it pulls it out as text. I would like to use Jquery therefore to find and replace the < > brackets so that it does render as an  tag instead.

Here's my source code:

```
<div class="custom_meta">
<strong>CODE: </strong>JL16<br>
<strong>Colour: </strong>&lt;img src="http://localhost:81/live_products/shop/wp-content/uploads/blue.gif" /&gt;<br>
<strong>COLOURS: </strong>BLACK, WHITE, GREY, CORAL, BLUE<br>
<strong>FABRIC: </strong>LYCRA<br>
</div>
```

Here's how I think it should be working in jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    // Remove "" from meta image
    jQuery(".custom_meta").replace(/&lt;/g, '<');
    jQuery(".custom_meta").replace(/&gt;/g, '>');

});
```

Would this be the right way to replace the `&lt;` to < and the `&gt;` to >
?

Thank you.

Comment: Just a tip: `jQuery(function($){   /*now use $ freely */ });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it

```
jQuery(".product_description").html(function(i, currenthtml){
   return currenthtml.replace(/&lt;/g, '<').replace(/&gt;/g, '>');
});
```

Read more at the [documentation about `.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2)